# Can I disable X-Frame-Options on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cross-domain

I'm testing an internal web application that pulls content from servers that I'd rather leave 100% alone, and some of them send the "[X-Frame-Options](http://blog.mozilla.com/security/2010/09/08/x-frame-options/)" header.  While that's the right setting in production, while we're testing, I'd like to strip it out on just our browsers.

Is that possible? Googling turned up nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put an intermediary proxy like [**WebScarab**](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) in the middle.  It'll allow you to rewrite responses on the fly so you should be able to strip that header out.

Comment: That's close to what I'm doing, I'm just running everything through Fiddler2 and looking at it there.  For the small amount of traffic I need to test it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an add-in for Firefox which ignores all x-frame options, see https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ignore-x-frame-options/

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881789/disable-x-frame-option-on-client-side/31391703

Answer (score 0):

A Firefox extension allows to do that: See "[Ignore X-Frame-Options Header](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ignore-x-frame-options-header/)" on addons.mozilla.org